# Misunderstanding of python 3 map

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda, generator

Python 3 map returns a generator. But I want to apply my function immediately without going through generator.
My code is:

```
printme = lambda x: print(x)

list(map(printme, fields))
for _ in map(printme, fields): pass
```

Why I have to build list or dive into loop? Why I can't just write **map(printme, fields)**? This idiom was working well for Python 2. What I have missed? Or how I can achieve this goal another way?

Comment: It worked in Python 2, but it was never an idiom.

Comment: `map` is all about collecting return values.  You're using it for side-effects rather than return values, which is non-standard use.    I suggest writing your own map replacement that reflects your intent.  Something like `def apply_to_all(func, iterable):for item in iterable:func(item)`.

Comment: Now that print is a function, print(*fields) works to do what I believe map(printme, fields) did, and it does not require a def or lambda.